# how can i connect my react-native app to my local node js server running at port 8200

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have a project which has a configuration file to connect to the server whereby providing backend API address provided as below

I am trying to connect it to the node.js server connected with MongoDB running at port
Server running on 8200
Mongoose connected to mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/booze_dev

```
export default {
  API_ROOT:'http://192.168.225.40:8081',
      // API_ROOT: 'https://api.abc.com/api',
};
```

but after trying it to connect locally with my device IP and port given by react-native run-android, but it is not hitting the backend running any help would be great and helpful

Answer (score 0):

Run this command with the adb:

```
adb reverse tcp:8200 tcp:8200
```